# What is $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty }\frac{n^x}{n!},\ n\in \mathbb Z^+,\ x\in \mathbb R$? Does $n^x$ or $n!$ grow faster as $n\to \infty $?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

The question just pops up in my head. $n^x$ is just an exponential function with positive integer base. My intuition is that $n^x$ grows faster so the limit should be infinity. How do we properly prove this divergence though?

Comment: is $x\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Do you know Sterling's approximation for the factorial - worth checking for this kind of question

Comment: The factorial even [outgrows exponentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131506/what-is-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fracxnx-does-xn-or-x-grow-fast), so it grow *much* faster than polynomials...

Comment: @CSquared yes it is

Comment: So, perhaps I'm missing something, but what is $n$? Is it a fixed natural number, or is it allowed to vary (perhaps depending on $x$)?

Comment: Along the lines of Nicholas Stull's question, the more interesting question is what happens to $x^x / x!$ (this is essentially the content of Stirling's approximation). OP's "my intuition is that the numerator grows faster" comment makes more sense with this modification, since $x^x \ge x!$ pointwise, but if $n$ is fixed, the numerator grows very slowly as others have pointed out.

Comment: Agh, now $n$ and $x$ have been swapped by OP

Comment: @AndyZ After the edit: "*$n^x$ is just an exponential function*" - no, it's a power function with fixed exponent. What varies in your $n^x$ is $n$, not $x$.

Comment: My apologies to all for not making the question very clear. I have corrected the notation now and the ranges of $n$ and $x$ are specified as well.

Comment: If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed, use Stirling's approximation to conclude that $n^x$ grows slower than $n!$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: without using stirlings, it would suffice to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^m}{n!}=0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @CSquared Could you give me a hint how?

Comment: @CSquared I got it.